# making a list of int from navigation property field of an Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have Models Like this

```
public class Product 
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTags> ProductTags { get; set; }

}

public class ProductTags 
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public long TagId { get; set; }
}

 public class Cart:BaseEntity
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
}


public class CartItem
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual  Product Product { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public long CartId { get; set; }

}
```

I want to have a list of all TagId for all products in a cartId

```
   CartItems 
   ==========================
   Id     cartId        ProductId    Count      
   ------------------------------------------
    1       1              1          10   
    2       1              2          20
    3       2              1          40

     ProductTags 
   ==========================
   Id     ProductId    TagId    
   ---------------------------
   1        1            1
   2        1            2
   3        2            1
   4        2            3
   5        3            4
```

I want the result be like this List list="1,2,3"

so I did this

```
  list = _context.CartItems
                .Where(p => p.CartId == cartId)
                .Include(p => p.Product)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductTags)
                .SelectMany(p => p.Product.ProductTags)
                .Select(p => p.TagId).ToList();
```

but it returns 0,where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

That is a hard question if I don't test with yours tables, but you can try somthing like this. The result will be a list of lists for all tagIds for any CartItem with given cartId

```
var list = _context.CartItems
                .Include(x => x.Product)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductTags)
                .Where(x => x.CartId == cartId)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    List = x.Product
                    .ProductTags
                    .Select(x => x.TagId)
                    .ToList(),
                })
                .ToList();
```